# convergence of random variable in $L^2$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

What would be a pragmatic method to inevstigate the convergence in $L^2$ of a sequence of random variables $X_n$ defined on $\Omega=[0,1]$ by $X_n(\omega)=\omega n$, with Lebesgue measure on $\Omega$?

Would something like this work: $\mathbb{E}(X_n^2)=\int_0^1(\omega n)^2d\omega$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ this integral does not converge?

Edit2:

I figured out it would be enough to just show if the following integral converges or it doesn't.

$\mathbb{E}(X_n^2)=\int_0^1 x^2n^2dx$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$

Any input is appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate $\| X_n \|_2$ and show that it diverge. And if $\| X_n \|_2$ diverge, then $X_n$ cannot converge in $L^2$.

Indeed, if $X_n \to X$ in $L^2$, then $\|X_n - X\| \to 0$, and it follow that $| \|X_n\| - \|X\| | \to 0$, hence $\|X_n\| \to \|X\|$, so $\|X_n\|$ must converge.